# acceptsFirstResponder in NSViewController and xcode 6 - Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6, nsviewcontroller

Could somebody explain to me how I can set acceptsFirstResponder on a NSViewController in Swift and xcode 6?

The program doesn't allow any overriding of the function and says it doesn't exist in the superclass but I can also not set it as a variable like:

```
self.acceptsFirstResponder = true
```

Anybody know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar issue but with a NSView Class. I was able to make this work with the following. I had to put it in the class outside any functions.

```
import Cocoa


class MyView: NSView, NSDraggingDestination {

//MARK: Variables

override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { return true }
override var opaque: Bool { return true }
var bgColor : NSColor = .yellowColor()
var lastString : String = ""
var attributes : NSMutableDictionary = [:]
var highlightNeeded = false
```